# Multiple Multivariate Normals in R with apply

Tags: r, apply

So, I'm trying to generate random numbers from multivariate normal distributions with different means.  I'm also trying to use the apply functions and not for loops, which is where the problem occurs.  Here is my code:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(123)

# X and Y means
Means<-cbind(c(.2,.2,.8),c(.2,.6,.8))
Means
Sigma<-matrix(c(.01,0,0,.01),nrow=2)
Sigma

data<-apply(X=Means,MARGIN=1,FUN=mvrnorm,n=10,Sigma=Sigma)
data
```

Instead of getting two vector with X and Y points for the three means, I get three vectors with X and Y points stacked.  What is the best way to get the two vectors?  I know I could unstack them manually, but I feel R should have some slick way of getting this done.

Comment: WTB In this case, rows 1:10 belong to `X` or is it alternating rows?

Comment: If you run the code and look at the second column of 'data', the first 10 are around .2 (second X mean) and the second 10 are around .6 (second Y mean).  So, I'm assuming rows 1:10 belong to X.

Comment: WTB, By checking with `lapply`, it seems to be not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not sure if it's what I would call 'slick' but if you really want to use apply (instead of lapply as previously mentioned), you can force apply to return your results as a list of matrices.  Then it's just a matter of sticking the results together. I expect that this would be less error-prone than trying to rebuild a two column matrix.

```
data <- apply(Means, 1, function(x) {
    list(mvrnorm(n=10, mu=x, Sigma=Sigma))
})
data <- do.call('rbind', unlist(data, recursive=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 set.seed(42)
 res1 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(Means)), function(i) mvrnorm(Means[i,], n=10, Sigma))
```

Checking with the results of `apply`

```
 set.seed(42)
 res2 <- apply(X=Means,MARGIN=1,FUN=mvrnorm,n=10,Sigma=Sigma)
 dim(res2) <- c(10,2, 3)
 res3 <-lapply(1:dim(res2)[3], function(i) res2[,,i])
 all.equal(res3, res1, check.attributes=FALSE)
 #[1] TRUE
```